# Does this code use soft attention or hard attention?

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation, attention-model, unet-neural-network

I'm new to deep learning. May I ask if the code below uses soft attention or hard attention?

```
class AttentionBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, f_g, f_l, f_int):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.w_g = nn.Sequential(
                                nn.Conv2d(f_g, f_int,
                                         kernel_size=1, stride=1,
                                         padding=0, bias=True),
                                nn.BatchNorm2d(f_int)
        )
        
        self.w_x = nn.Sequential(
                                nn.Conv2d(f_l, f_int,
                                         kernel_size=1, stride=1,
                                         padding=0, bias=True),
                                nn.BatchNorm2d(f_int)
        )
        
        self.psi = nn.Sequential(
                                nn.Conv2d(f_int, 1,
                                         kernel_size=1, stride=1,
                                         padding=0,  bias=True),
                                nn.BatchNorm2d(1),
                                nn.Sigmoid(),
        )
        
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        
    def forward(self, g, x):
        g1 = self.w_g(g)
        x1 = self.w_x(x)
        psi = self.relu(g1+x1)
        psi = self.psi(psi)
        
        return psi*x
```

Source: https://www.kaggle.com/code/truthisneverlinear/attention-u-net-pytorch/notebook#Attention-U-Net

I didn't know the differences between soft attention and hard attention.

Answer (score 0):

Hard attention makes a "hard" (attention values are 0 or 1) decision on which input/region to focus on. Whereas soft attention makes a "soft" decision ( all values lie in the range [0, 1]); a probability distribution. Generally, soft attention is used and preferred since its differentiable.

A good starting point is to look at the corresponding [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03999).

> We propose one of the first use cases of soft-attention technique in a feed-forward CNN
> model applied to a medical imaging task.

In the code you can see that they use a `sigmoid` activation in the last layer to normalize to the range [0, 1].